# Store and Group <Key> based on <Value> of All Dictionary Records Where <Value> Matches X

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `Dictionary`, `CustomerInfo_Dict`, which stores `CustomerID (Key) | Age (Value)`

1. Get distinct `Age (Value)`
2. Add matched `CustomerID (Key)` base on each distinct `Age (Value)` into an `Array/List/other type`

   ```
    foreach (var CustomerInfo_Dict_DistinctAge in CustomerInfo_Dict.Values.Distinct())
    {
        foreach (var CustomerInfo in CustomerInfo_Dict)
        {
            //if (CustomerInfo <Value>:Age) == (CustomerInfo_Dict_DistinctAge <Value>:Age)
            {
                //add matched `CustomerID (Key)` to a separate List
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: So you want to swap your dictionary around? Create a dictionary that maps ages->list-of-ids-with-that-age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only needs one loop (non LINQ)

```
var ageToIds = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

foreach(var kvp in idToAge){
  if(!ageToIds.ContainsKey(kvp.Value))
    ageToIds[kvp.Value] = new List<int>();

  ageToIds[kvp.Value].Add(kvp.Key);
}
```

And with LINQ, we can have LINQ do a group on the Value (age) which will become the key, and the whole KeyValuePair becomes the List of values (from which we can then select just the Key.. but note it's the KeyValuePair's Key, not the grouping's Key):

```
var ageToIds = idToAge
  .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
  .ToDictionary(
    g => g.Key,
    g => g.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList()
  );
```

You might even be able to skip the dictionary part, because a Linq IGrouping is nearly the same thing:

```
var ageToIdsGrouping = idToAge
  .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key);
```

This gives you an GroupedEnumerable which is like a dictionary if you enumerate it; being collection of Grouping, each Grouping having a Key (which is the age) and being itself a enumerable of ints (which are the ids)

```
foreach(var g in ageToIdsGrouping){
      int age = g.Key;
      var ids = g;     //it's an enumerable list of the IDs
      string idsString = string.Join(',', ids);
        
      Console.WriteLine($"{age}: {idsString}");
}
```

---

If you had this before:

```
idToAge[123] = 30;
idToAge[234] = 30;
idToAge[345] = 30;
idToAge[456] = 31;
```

You should have this:

```
ageToIds[30] = { 123, 234, 345 };
ageToIds[31] = { 456 };
```

To get all the lists:

```
foreach(var kvp in ageToIds){

  int age = kvp.Key;

  List<int> ids = kvp.Value;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am attempting your non-LINQ version. I see that you have added `value` to a `new List` if there is no match in Key. After the run, do I get all created lists by looping through each key via `foreach(var kvp in idToAge)` to retrieve all `ageToIds[kvp.Value]` lists created?

*apologies, I meant to say that I am unable to think of the method to get all the created lists after the above have been run.